# Add custom post to a custom post type page

Tags: wordpress, post, types, field, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type named Books, I have another one called videos.

I want to add videos and select on which book it will show..

I don't know what to search for, or if its even posible?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are so many approaches to make this work, but I'm used to implement Typerocket to get custom post types working fast and easy. This library helps you to create custom post types and customize the create/edit section at the wp-admin.

It has a post type search that I think can fit your needs:
https://typerocket.com/docs/v3/field-types/#section-search-search-post-types

You can use it to link other post type to your Books post type.

Edit -
Then at the view you can get the list of videos linked at backoffice and show them the way you want (using books-single.php template).

Hope this helps, greetings.